# Regex with PHP preg_replace() need to find the nearest name in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I need to find the nearest name in string how would I do this ?

The closest I got was the apposite and it finds the furthest away from string is:

```
$string = "joe,bob,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,bob,marco,luis";

$new_string = preg_replace('/(bob(?!.*bob))/', 'found it!', $string);

echo $new_string;
<!-- outputs: joe,bob,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,found it!,marco,luis -->
```

How would I do the apposite ? and have an output like this:

```
<!-- outputs: joe,found it!,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,bob,marco,luis -->
```

Comment: try using the 4th param (`limit`) of preg_replace equal to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a negative lookbehind instead, like this

```
$string = "joe,bob,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,bob,marco,luis";

$new_string = preg_replace('/((?<!bob)bob)/', 'found it!', $string, 1);

echo $new_string;
<!-- outputs: joe,found it!,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,bob,marco,luisoff -->
```

As Wiktor said, use the limit option to match only the first occurrence of the name.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you are using `(bob(?!.*bob))` matches the last occurrence of `bob` (not as a whole word) on a line, because the `.` matches any character but a newline, and the negative lookahead makes sure there is no `bob` after `bob`. See [what your regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/dP1oC0/1) (if we use `preg_replace` with default options).

You may use

```
$re = '/\bbob\b/'; 
$str = "joe,bob,luis,sancho,bob,marco,lura,hannah,bob,marco,luis"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, 'found it!', $str, 1);
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nmRf9j)

The regex `\bbob\b` will match a whole word, and using the `limit` argument will only match the first occurrence of the word 'bob'.

See [`preg_replace` help](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

> **limit**
>   The maximum possible replacements for each pattern in each subject string. Defaults to `-1` (no limit).

Comment: Lookarounds are unnecessary overhead for this task.  Wiktor's answer is the optimal choice here.